# How to read/write trait with case objects using play-json

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I have a following structure:

```
  sealed trait Animal {
    def name: String
    def kind: String
  }

  case object Dog extends Animal {
    override def name: String = "A"
    override def kind: String = "B"
  }

  case object Whale extends Animal {
    override def name: String = "C"
    override def kind: String = "B"
  }
```

How I can read/write it to/from json with `play-json`? It simple for `writes`, but how about `reads`?

Answer (score 0):

You need `case classes` NOT `case objects`, like:

```
sealed trait Animal {
    def name: String
    def kind: String
  }

  case class Dog(name: String = "A", kind: String = "B") extends Animal 

  case class Whale(name: String = "C", kind: String = "B") extends Animal
```

Or if you have static values us an Enumeration from [enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum#play-json)

Comment: Okey, but can I protect class  from non default values?

Comment: How such `object` would make sense? Except for some limited tests?

Comment: @zella I think then Enumerations are the better way - see my link.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to stick with the case objects, you can define a custom `Writer` /`Reader`

```
import play.api.libs.json._
implicit val w: Writes[Animal] = {
  case d @ _ => Json.obj(
    "name" -> d.name,
    "kind" -> d.kind
  )
}
Json.toJson(Dog)
```

You may customize it to handle each object separately, so that you can handle the cases which you introduce new fields in a case object.

Comment: Even using `object`, there is no need for a custom handler with a recent Play-JSON version